# Union structure in Ruby

Tags: ruby, structure, unions

Can I use `union` structure in `ruby language`? 
Is there `union structure` in Ruby? 
If there is, could you show me an example code? 
Or if there isn't, could you tell me the reason why ruby doesn't have union?

Edit: 
Just added the example below to clarify the question which was not clear. :)

```
struct byte_nibbles {
    unsigned char b1: 4;
    unsigned char b2: 4;
    unsigned char b3: 4;
    unsigned char b4: 4;
    unsigned char b5: 4;
    unsigned char b6: 4;
    unsigned char b7: 4;
    unsigned char b8: 4; };
};
union {
    unsigned long var;
    struct byte_nibbles b;
} u;
```

Comment: Are you asking about C union structures that have their data mapped to the same address? Or Haskell style "union" types, more commonly known as "sum type" or "tagged union"? Or are you asking about something similar to SQL's union keyword, which you have tagged this question with.

Comment: I mean, the thing kind of C union structures that have data to the same address. Thanks you.

Comment: I can't say with 100% certainty, but I'm fairly certain Ruby has nothing like that. The main reason is that in Ruby, you do not manage your programs memory manually, you let the ruby interpreter do that for you. Now, internally Ruby maybe using unions for optimizations.

Comment: In a very real sense, Ruby has complete support for unions in the C sense. You see in C, unions are used to as a primitive, type unsafe sort of dynamic typing. A variable can be one of a number of types. In Ruby all variables are dynamic and type safe, so it has the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby is dynamic and does the memory management for you.

So if you need this kind of C union :

```
union Data {
   int i;
   float f;
   char str[20];
} data;
```

you actually don't need to define anything in Ruby, but just use it :

```
data = 3
puts data
data = 3.14159
puts data
data = "Ruby"
puts data
# =>
# 3
# 3.14159
# Ruby
```

NOTE : MRI Ruby (= Ruby written in C) uses C Unions, for example for Arrays, depending on their length. If you want more info, I highly recommend [Ruby under a microscope](http://patshaughnessy.net/ruby-under-a-microscope).